# How to crop image within a circle div in css?

Tags: html, css

[image: example]

Hi there, I want to crop the image within a div that is divided into two parts in a circle. One side is half cropped pic and the other side is just background color with the name on it. I am currently using following code :
width: 220px;

```
userdp {
    height: 220px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: none;
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code and the result you want to get,

Comment: What is some name will be too long to fit? have you thought about that?

Comment: Edited my answer slightly. Check back for the updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is inside the `div` element that you're applying that styling to as below you should just need to add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS.

```
<div class="userdp">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

And the styling.

```
.userdp {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've created an example here for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/20g4uL0j/1/

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` and a little more play with the positioning, `z-index`, and `object-fit` may help you achieve that.

Here is an example for you (EDITED after re-reading your question):

```css
.userdp {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.userdp-img {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.userdp-info {
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.userdp-info-inner {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.userdp-img,
.userdp-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="userdp">
  <div class="userdp-info">
    <div class="userdp-info-inner">
      John Doe
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300?image=1005" class="userdp-img">
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

```
**HTML**
<div class="circle">
<div class="image">
    <img src="your-image.png" />
</div>
<div class="color">Text</div>
```

```
**CSS**
.circle{
width: 220px;
height:220px;
border-radius: 50%;
overflow:hidden;
}
.image, .color{
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 height:100%;
 }
.color{
background-color: #099;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follow:

https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/f1a06cxe/

```css
div {
  background: #9e978e;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  height: 55px;
  width: 110px;
}

.right,
.left {
  height: 110px;
  width: 55px;
}

.top {
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
}

.right {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 110px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
}

.left {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```